# when i want to build i have this error

Tags: android, build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] C:\Users\kamal.android\build-cache\a14382872a293855060ea80fddf386831adf48b2\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.carpedeem.bonne"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23

    ndk {
        modandroid {
            uleName "player_shared"



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/PTAdChartboost.jar')
compile files('libs/PTAdRevMob.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

}

Comment: [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] use minSdkVersion >=14.. so you need to set your minSdkVersion >= 14 also

Comment: how to do it please ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to update your `minSdkVersion 11` to `minSdkVersion 14` in  the `defaultConfig` of your gradle file.

It means that your application must not have `minSdkVersion` (minimum SDK version) lesser than the `minSdkVersion` of any of the libraries that you're using - in your case [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] library with minimum SDK of 14.

update your gradle file and build project again.

Comment: yes i do that and i have an other eroor   Error:(3, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [23] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: That's an entirely separate problem. It is unrelated to your original issue. You'll have to post a new question for this problem because it can't be solved with such little details and in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `minSdkVersion` to 14 in your `build.gradle` app and upgrade your `compileSdkVersion` to 7.0 and your `buildToolsVersion` to 26.0.0.